# How to avoid getting a negative value of quantity?

Tags: php, mysql

How to get rid of negative value of quantity in database.
When i set the quantity of an item to 1 and purchase the item with 1 quantity, the next purchase will get error.. but when i purchase the item with 1 quantity to 2 it will go success and in database i get -1 value of quantity.

```
 $quantityb = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['quantity']);
 $itemNameb = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['itemnameb']);
 $qry = "SELECT * FROM tool WHERE itemname = '$itemNameb' AND quantity > 0";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect,$qry);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 )
 {
$newvalue = $row['quantity'] - $quantityb;
$query_update = "UPDATE tool SET quantity = '$newvalue' WHERE 
itemname='$itemNameb'";
$update = mysqli_query($connect,$query_update);
}
  else
 {
$_SESSION['msg'] = "Item isn't Exist or Item is out of stock";
 }
 <form action = "" method = "post">
Item Name:<input type = "text" name = "itemnameb" required>
Quantity:<input type = "number" name = "quantity" required>
 <input type = "submit" name = "submit"></td>
 </form>
```

Comment: In your query, instead of `quantity > 0`, you could query items that has equal to or more than the quantity the user wants to purchase. Then you will only get items that has enough quantity and you won't get -1.  Something like: `AND quantity >= theRequestedQuantity`.  You should also use Prepared Statements instead of concatenating your queries.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson so i will just echo the available quantity of an item?

Comment: What keeps you from writing the appropriate code for this problem?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "echo" the quantity. Just check if the item has enough quantity before you assume it does. Right now, you're just checking if it's not zero, but you're not checking if it has enough.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sir, i don't know what to change or where to insert a prepared statement or how not to concatenate my queries.. and cant find a good example for prepared statement to study.

Comment: There are _many_ tutorials about prepared statements. You could start by checking the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` in SQL. However, if you are using MySQL, `CHECK`s are parsed as valid syntax but not processed by the database engine.

You could model your SQL query to include the constraint in the `WHERE` condition:

```
$query_update = "UPDATE tool SET quantity = quantity - $quantityb WHERE itemname='$itemNameb' AND (quantity - $quantityb) >= 0";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newvalue = max($row['quantity'] - $quantityb, 0);
```

Or if you want to throw an error just check if the quantity you want to purchase is less or equal than the available quantity before the update.

Comment: yeah this one avoids me to get a negative value.. but if i purchase greater than its quantity it still go success and add it into my database.